# How to trigger a click on a Vaadin element from console

Tags: javascript, automation, vaadin

I have a Vaadin generated webpage. On that page I have a grid of cells. When I click a cell it becomes highlighted (it becomes surrounded by a blue frame).

I would like to trigger that click from the Javascript console (Chrome or FF). Usually, I can do it successfully with simple `element.click()` but that doesn't work in this occasion. I assume that it have some to do with being Vaadin generated?

How can I trigger the selection of this cell in such case?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an id of the button in vaadin like this:

```
Button btn=new Button("Click Here");
btn.setId("mybtn");
..
..
```

Then try getting the element by this id in your javascript using `getElementById("mybtn")`

I think it should work

Comment: Hi, I am no trying to get an element, I already have it. My problem is performing the click. I don't have access to Vaadin either. I only mentioned that this page was generated using Vaadin.